# Code golfing my guess the number game with feedback in NS-HUBASIC - Can it be code golfed any further?

Tags: code-golf, random, tips, game, basic

The player has to keep guessing a number from 1 to 10 until they guess the correct number to win the game. If they make an incorrect guess, they're told if their guess was too low or too high.

Each line has to render below the previous line for me to accept the solution as the new code for the game (However, you can still share any solutions that break that rule.). For example, no lines can be rendered over other lines, such as "CORRECT." over "TOO LOW." or "TOO HIGH.".

Here's the code:

```
0N=RND(10)+1:DIMT$(2):T$(0)="CORRECT.":T$(1)="TOO LOW.":T$(2)="TOO HIGH.":F.T=0TO0:I."WHAT'S MY NUMBER? (1-10) ",G:T=G<>N:?T$(-(G>N)-T):N.
```

As for how I'm running NS-HUBASIC code, I'm doing it in Family BASIC V3.0, which I'm running under Nestopia v1.40.

If you need any documentation, you can find it here: https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/nes/938747-family-basic-v3/faqs/59317

Comment: I estimate a quite small number of NS-HUBASIC coders here. Maybe you could recommend some online documentation and/or environment/emulator so others could try jumping in.

Comment: Where is the online documentation for NS-HUBASIC?

Comment: I just added a link to some documentation for NS-HUBASIC, which is online, to the initial post. But here's the link here (I hope it'll make it more convenient for you to find the link): https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/nes/938747-family-basic-v3/faqs/59317

Comment: The ROM can be tried online [here](https://nesgamezone.com/play/family-basic-japan-v30-nes-rom-2552.html), but it seems to be complaining about the keyboard not being plugged and I don't think there's a way to enable it in this emulator. (Or is it?)

Answer (score 2):

## <s>134</s>  133 characters

Note: I don't know for sure whether a line-break counts as 1 character.

```
0N=RND(10)+1:DIMT$(2):T$(0)="TOO LOW.":T$(1)="CORRECT.":T$(2)="TOO HIGH."
1I."WHAT'S MY NUMBER? (1-10) ",G:?T$(SGN(G-N)+1):IF G-N T.1
```

#### Example output

[image: output]

Comment: I also asked this question at NesDev (I had found no answers where I had asked it before (NesDev ([Link](https://forums.nesdev.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=19950)) and Famicom World ([Link 1](https://famicomworld.com/forum/index.php?topic=14576.0)) and ([Link 2](https://famicomworld.com/forum/index.php?topic=14795.0)) are those places), so I asked it at StackOverflow). Controllerhead there helped me get here, down from 133 characters to 131 characters. Code: 0N=RND(10)+1:F.T=0TO0:I."WHAT'S MY NUMBER? (1-10) ",G:T=G<>N:RES.0:F.I=0TO(-(G>N)-T):READC$:N.:?C$:N.:D.CORRECT.,TOO LOW.,TOO HIGH.

Comment: @NiallWard I clearly couldn't have gone that far, as the above code snippet is the first (and perhaps the last) thing I ever wrote in this language. :-)

Comment: I thank you, Controllerhead and anyone else who may have helped me get the program to the length it's at now for the help.